# Java input stops working when window is unfocused

Tags: java

today I added keyboard input to my game the way I always do, with `KeyListener`, but for some reason, in my program whenever I click outside of the window and click back in, the key input just stops working. Here is what I have in my `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    switch (code) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
        keys[0] = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
        keys[1] = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
        keys[2] = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        keys[3] = true;
        break;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    switch (code) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
        keys[0] = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
        keys[1] = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
        keys[2] = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        keys[3] = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not much to go on.  Have you set breakpoints in these methods? What have you done so far to debug this?

Comment: Do you do any processing in response to window focus events? (More specifically, in response to unfocus events?)

Comment: @JimGarrison I have studied this for hours with no luck. This has never happened before.

Comment: @TedHopp No I never have to

Comment: How are you setting up the key listener? Perhaps you need to listen to window focus/unfocus events and register/unregister the key listener in response. (However, using key bindings is better, if you are using Swing components.)

Comment: @TedHopp Is there a way I can just do something like `frame.activateKeyListener()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyListener` is notorious for having focus issues.  In order for a `KeyListener` to raise an event, the component it is registered to must not only be focusable, but must have focus.

Instead, you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which have mechanisms for overcoming these short comings

**Amendment**

If you're using AWT components you have another (few) problems. Essentially, you need to make the component focusable an when the use clicks on call requestFocusInWindow

Comment: A sandwich can be nutritious, but I don't know how a `KeyListener` could be. Perhaps you mean "notorious"? (+1 for pointing to the most likely problem, btw)

Comment: @TedHopp I thought about saying "a complete pain in the a**", but thought that was going over the top ;)

Comment: I looked at whats at that link, but how do I add key bindings for a awt canvas, or a Jframe?

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't (and it's not required).  Instead, create a base component (say `JPanel`) and use it instead and use `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` for the `InputMap` condition

Comment: If you're using AWT components you have another (few) problems.  Essentially, you need to make the component focusable an when the use clicks on call `requestFocusInWindow`

Comment: I fixed it. I just added `frame.requestFocusInWindow()` in the game loop like MadProgrammer mentioned, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be trying to do animation of a component with the keyboard. See [Motion With the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) which explains some problems with using the a KeyListener and shows how you might use Key Bindings.